# bind in fstab not automounted

Tags: fstab

I have bougth a SSD drive, moved my system partiton to it, but I want to use my "slow" disk to store photos and videos. I have created fstab entries which work, but they are not mounted automatically. Is there a way to force them?

I am on xUbutnu 16.04 and my fstab is:

```
UUID=ea22f3c5-029b-42eb-8baf-3b55d0928ca7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,barrier=0   0 1
/dev/sda2       none            swap    sw              0       0
/home/user/Música     /home/user2/Música bind bind
/dev/sda1               /mnt/slow                       ext4    defaults,rw     0 0
/home/user/Imatges    /mnt/slow/user/Imatges        none    defaults,bind   0 0
/home/user/Vídeos     /mnt/slow/user/Vídeos         none    defaults,bind   0 0
/home/user/Baixades   /mnt/slow/user/Baixades       none    defaults,bind   0 0
```

thanks

Comment: How do you know that they work? Does `mount -a` mount these? Or how can you say "it works" ? Also your third line is missing the dump and pass parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, I have mispelled the third line.

My file was wrong, I misplaced origin/destination so I was mounting an empty folder over a full folder, and I was thinking it wasn't working while it was mounting it.

Thanks for your time